# Dynamic Data Display - get horizontal and vertical from ChartPlotter

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, location, dynamic-data-display

I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2010, wpf, Dynamic Data Display, ChartPlotter (map) that I should take the point on the map exactly, the horizental is working perfect, but the vertical is inaccurate, its give wrong position.

code :

```
   private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = e.GetPosition(this.plotter.CentralGrid);
            Point ps = this.plotter.Viewport.Transform.ScreenToViewport(pt);

            lbl_X.Content = ps.X.ToString();
            lbl_Y.Content = ps.Y.ToString();
        }
```

the lbl_Y.Content is inaccurate.
the function is MouseMove on the plotter.
Thanks for help. good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i found the answer, if anyone need:

```
Point pt = e.GetPosition(this.plotter.CentralGrid);
Point ps = this.plotter.Viewport.Transform.ScreenToViewport(pt);

lbl_X.Content = ps.X.ToString();
lbl_Y.Content = this.plotter.Viewport.Transform.DataTransform.ViewportToData(ps).Y.ToString();
```